# Nullpointer exception error when clicking on my toolbar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()` when I click on a button in my toolbar.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Legg til notat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.leggtilnotat:
            Intent leggtilnotat = new Intent(Notatliste.this, LeggtilNotat.class);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            String id = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbId);
            String navn = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbnavn);


            databaseNotater = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notater").child(id);

            startActivity(leggtilnotat);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

What could be the problem here?

Comment: *What could be the problem here?* - try  reading the error message

Comment: I read it, but don't understand what it is. I'm a beginner at this, so I'm just trying to get some help.

Comment: Without an error log, it's difficult to point to the error. From a look at this code maybe the problem is in this line: `databaseNotater = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notater").child(id);`. Check if `id` is `null`.

Comment: Can you paste the log cat?

Comment: @Android4Fun I manage to get this to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child(path)` does not accept null arguments. Make sure the id is not null.